# Session Resumption caching in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, cache

Some days ago i read a blogpost about session resumption in nginx.

In that text the author claims that nginx does not provide the ability to regularly clear the session cache.
After "ssl_session_timeout" has expired, the session is no longer used, 
but the file is still on the hard disk and could be read by an attacker 
therefore "Forward Secrecy" would be useless at this point.

Instead of using Session ID's, he suggests deactivating the Session Cache 
and using session tickets. 
To do this, a "ticket_key" with 80 bytes of randomness must be created at least once a day.

I searched the internet for more information but couldn't find anything helpful.

Q1: What is the location of the nginx session cache and how could I check if TLS connection data(sessions) 
    are on the hard disk?

Q2: Is it advisable to use Session Tickets?

Comment: AFAIK both methods have security issues, and neither is safe for an environment requiring forward secrecy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t answer the first question but can talk a little about the second.

This blog post gives some good info on flaws with session tickets on TLSv1.2: https://blog.filippo.io/we-need-to-talk-about-session-tickets/.

So like Michael says they both have their problems and only if you use TLSv1.3 ([literally just signed off](https://www.ietf.org/blog/tls13/) and so just becoming available in implementations at the time of writing) can you use TLS resumption completely safely.

However saying that the performance cost of not using TLS session resumption is significant, and IMHO the risks are relatively low (if someone has access to your server then it’s game over as far as I’m concerned). So for now I recommend using both session ids and session tickets. Especially as some clients (Safari and IE on Windows 7 and earlier) don’t support session tickets. Safari in particularly still has a lot of users on mobile and tablet  - do you really want to significantly slow down all iOS users?

Comment: It depends. For your personal blog - probably you don't care much about forward secrecy. For your e-commerce site - probably you do care about keeping customers' credit card numbers secured.

Comment: Well Amazon, PayPal and EBay as a sample check all use both session caching and tickets. As I say the performance impact is too high compared to the risk you are protecting against IMHO.